# Is it okay to structure a non-normal table in relational database to achieve a fast query?

Tags: relational-database, normalization

Let's say we've got 3 entities here, User, Tag, Track and a single associative entity called Tagged.
[image: ERD]

I need to count a tag frequency of a track and the common way is to count the record of tagged, but what if I just store the tag's frequency as an integer attribute on Tag entity, and maintain the value every time there are changed on Tagged's record, will it be a problem ?

Edit:
The DBMS I'm using is MySQL 5.6.
About the dataset, there are 947 tracks, 7962 tags, 800~ users, and 366617 taggeds

Why I need to query it fast ? Because, I'm trying to calculate similarity value between each track and in that process I need to obtain the frequency of each tag of the tracks I'm calculating and I think the slow query is where it should obtain the frequency from counting the record on Tagged, that's why I think maybe I should just directly store the frequency instead of count through those records.

Comment: Its called de-normalizing, and its fine, as long as you know why you are doing it.

Comment: @GrandmasterB This is not de-normalizing. The relational normal forms don't address redundancies based on aggregate functions.

Comment: Could you possibly explain why you think it is a good idea to store (and maintain) the tag count and what DB technology you use ? To further help us giving objective advise, could you also indicate: how many users run the report and how often,  if there are other reasons than the report for getting the tag count, how many users that created tagged entries and how often, as well as volumes of your dataset ?

Comment: also, what is the slow query you are trying to avoid running?

Comment: I've added the explanation on the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only record derivable information when absolutely necessary, after it's been observed that a query or view on the Tagged table isn't practical.

However, once the decision has been made to store this info, recording derivable information is fine, provided you maintain consistency. Consider implementing this as a trigger on the Tagged table to ensure consistency at the database level, so that direct-to-database changes (e.g. by a DBA) can't break your data.

BTW, your associative entity should just be a ternary relationship. Associative entities in the ER model are only required when a relationship needs to be the subject of another relationship.

Comment: While there are certainly some cases where such denormalizing could be justified, it is not the case here.  First, if there are many inserts and updates in 'tagged', your triggers would create a concurrency issue (a bottleneck in principle). Second, your triggers create a vendor lock-in that will make change of db difficult. Third, the triggers would absorb a part of the application logic, potentially breaking a clean architecture. Fourth, what will you recommend if the next report wants also stats on tags per user ?

Comment: Finally, I'd add that "premature optimization is the root of all evil": we don't even know if there's a real performance issue: the RDBMS engine should do very well with a GROUP BY clause, provided there are the right indexes.

Comment: @Christophe I agree that recording derivable information should only be done when absolutely necessary, after it's been observed that a query or view on the Tagged table isn't practical. However, once the decision has been made to store this info, a trigger ensures data integrity at the DB level and does it in a single transaction, instead of multiple calls from the app. Data integrity isn't "application logic", it's part of the data model and what database management systems were built to manage.

Comment: @Christophe Finally, using only the least common denominator functionality so that you can switch DBMSs easily will always leave you with the need to switch since you won't ever exploit the value of any of them.

Comment: I thank you for having taken my main concern in consideration in your edit! I hence removed my downvote. On the trigger question, I understand and appreciate your arguments even if I do not necessarily share them. But given the little we know over Edwin's context it will be difficult to continue the discussion on an objective ground ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Christophe. Context matters and it's every DBA's responsibility to evaluate and test the available solutions in their own environment. You raised good points and the questioner should consider all the answers and comments posted.

Comment: I would argue with having a database trigger. Database triggers not visible in application code, instead have one place in the code where actual saving happened.

Comment: @Fabio I would rather put it in the DB where I can ensure it executes as an atomic transaction to keep Tagged and Tag tables synchronized, and where it can be reused by multiple apps and DBAs. We can agree to disagree.

Comment: @reaanb, true if you still have DBAs or have business logic in the database procedures or update production data straight in the database. You don't need to have database trigger only to share logic between applications.

Answer (score 4):

I would not recommend doing this.

It complicates the database with what is essentially either a cached value or a report.

A cached value can be maintained better outside of the database

A report should be done on a reporting server.

I would *especially* not recommend using triggers to keep the value up to date. This could really slow your db down.

Your application could use any number of different aggregates and calculations, will you be adding each as an extra column on a table?

Run the aggregate query and cache the result in the application (invalidating when required), or run a report each day and use that.

On the whole adding the extra column is a very database-centric solution. If you have an application or API layer above the database you will have multiple options available to you to avoid this problem.

For example, if I always retrieve a Track and its Tags together to populate an aggregate object, then there is no need to calculate the number of tags on the database.

If I want to show the number of Tags per day, per week etc then a single col of on the track table no longer helps me. I can query Track + today's Tags from the transaction DB and the Tag frequency over time for that Track from the reporting Cube which will be optimised for that kind of query on historical data.

Even if I want an on demand up to the second report of the most frequently Tagged tracks over all time, for which a single, updated col would be useful. I would still not add the column. Instead I would have the application raise an event when a tag was added and deal with this in a completely separate solution, possibly statsd or a reporting cube that I would write directly to.

Comment: While denormalizing can sometimes be justified, I fully agree with your analysis for this case:  here it's a very bad idea ! Not only will there be concurrency issues with updates that change the relations, but furthermore, what will happen if the next reports want statistics on tags per user and so on ? For this kind of needs the rdbms engines's GROUP BY will do fine, provided there's the good indexes.

Comment: A whole reporting server is overkill for a few calculated values, there's a minimum critical mass required to make a separate server cost-effective. Below that threshold, it can be viable and valuable to manage some calculated data on the same server. As for "could really slow your db down", it could also really speed your db up, as I've seen with trigger-maintained closure tables for hierarchical data.

Comment: @Christophe The question doesn't involve denormalization. What normal forms are the tables in before and after the addition of the derived column?

Comment: @reaanb interesting debate :-) The definition of the normal form is based on relational algebra and functional dependencies (see Boyce-Codd normal form), not on tables and columns. Functional dependency means exactly what you call derivability. So introducing data that could be derived breaks the normal form, which is by definition denormalization.

Comment: @reaanb The extra col is a very DB centric solution, There are some good non-db solutions which I think the OP is missing. I'm not sure we have enough info to work out the _best_ solution. However, maybe you could specify what exact sql your proposed trigger would run?  If its just the 'slow query' the OP wants to avoid then its the same cost as a simple caching solution

Comment: @Christophe The relational model doesn't address functional dependencies over multiple relations (tables) and groups of rows, only functional dependencies between the components (columns) of a single relation (table). Adding a column to the Tag table that is functionally dependent on only the PK of that table might break 6NF at worst, but then it could be recorded in a separate table and still be considered an "attribute on the entity".

Comment: @Christophe For the triggers, I'd increment the tag frequency by 1 on insert, decrement it by 1 on delete, and increment for the new tag / decrement for the old tag when the tag_id is updated in the Tagged table.

Comment: @reaanb that avoids the 'slow query' but doesnt protect you against direct-to-db changes

Comment: @Ewan it maintains the tag frequency in case of normal transactions on the Tagged table. The point was that a user/app would only need to make changes in one place. With the triggers in place, there should be no need for anyone to update the frequency column directly. A naming convention on the column can help to clarify that. Protecting against potentially malicious users/code is a different matter but there are ways to do that too.

Comment: @reaanb sure, but you specifically said changes by the DBA. Also, it seems to me that that trigger could get pretty complicated with the Track and User options+ transactions and locking to deal with concurrent changes. I'm sure it can be done, but you are loading up the DB with logic to perform

Comment: @Ewan For MySQL InnoDB, SQL Server and PostgreSQL at least, a trigger executes in the same transaction as the statement that fired it, and AFAICS, the trigger logic I suggested above (increment and/or decrement by 1) is reliable under default isolation levels without additional locking requirements. As for Track and User, they have no bearing on the question.

Comment: @Ewan As for "loading up the DB with logic", would you rather put multi-statement transactions and locking into the DB so that apps and DBAs can reuse it to do logical updates with a single instruction, or do you want that logic spread out over multiple apps and hope DBAs remember how to do it?

Comment: @reaanb I would have all the logic in the api. I think you are wrong about the trigger. you have to decide which of two different tables to select from, take the value of the column add one and then write the result back. so you need a transaction and at least a row lock vs a single table insert